# How to use pgn viewer

Tags: support, pgn-viewer

This seems elementary enough, but how do I use the pgn viewer? I mean how to embed it in a question I want to ask. I searched the help center for "pgn" or "embed chess player" but none of those returned any results. This seems like it should be in the FAQ. Maybe it is and I missed it. What do I do? Is it some link I have to click? HTML code copy pasted from somewhere else? Some special LaTeX like syntax?

Comment: Check out this post: http://meta.chess.stackexchange.com/q/179/12

Comment: [This question](http://meta.chess.stackexchange.com/questions/279/tool-used-to-create-chess-analysis-interactive-diagrams-in-many-chess-stack-exch) might help yo as well. I know there are a lot of comments but go through them as well since they describe how to add titles, names of the players and so on. If you have further questions leave a comment and I will reply. Best regards and good luck!

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff thanks. checking it.